# what's the solution for andoid studio crashing after new update

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart, flutter-dependencies

**Hi there after the latest update for android studio while finishing the update I had an internet issue and the update didn't complete after i tried to open android studio again error message below poped up I even tried to reinstall android studio and start over scratch but another error message shown says that I didn't have uninstaller.exe ,what's the solution please without losing my progress I have a project seminar tomorrow and don't know what to do? **
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXHCL.png)

Answer (score 0):

Some solution you can try:

**solution 1**

Open the folder where you installed Android Studio:

> ex: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin

Find and edit `idea.properties`. You can edit this with use notepad++ or any similar application that allows text editing.

Add this line as the final in the file:

```
disable.android.first.run=true
```

Now run Android Studio again.

**solution 2**

1. Close Android Studio
2. Turn off Internet connection and be sure of it.
3. Start Android Studio. You will see a **popup box** with Cancel option in it. Then Click **cancel**.

**solution 3**

Restart your computer